# How to use OR (||) for form elements in single HTML page

Tags: javascript

Need to shorten (compile) multiple javascript functions into one function

I have (unsuccessfully) attempted assigned form elements to variables and calling those back. I am still very new... sorry!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confSubmit1()
{
    if(!document.getElementById("terms1").checked)
    { 
        alert("Please read and accept the Terms and Conditions");
        return false;
    }
    alert("You are now being redirected to PayPal");
    return true;    
}
function confSubmit2()
{
    if(!document.getElementById("terms2").checked)
    { 
        alert("Please read and accept the Terms and Conditions");
        return false;
    }
    alert("You are now being redirected to PayPal");
    return true;    
}
</script>
```

So, I have multiple forms on a single HTML page, all of which are for purchase via PayPal. Each form has a checkbox for the user to agree to the Terms based on which product they are purchasing.

I have attempted to shorten the above code into a single function using variables, etc., but I cannot for the life of me figure it out!

I am sure there is a way of using an OR (||) statement (or some other way) to put this all into a single function without having a function for each form. I got it to work like this but just seems like there is a better way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: _I have attempted to shorten the above code into a single function using variables, etc._ can you please show your attempt?

Comment: Update `if` condition in one function as `if (!document.getElementById("terms1").checked || !document.getElementById("terms2").checked)` & remove other function.

Comment: *I am still very new... sorry!* No need to apologize for being new. We're all new at some point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function confSubmit(id)
{
   var check = document.getElementById(id).checked;
   check ? alert("You are now being redirected to PayPal") : alert("Please read and accept the Terms and Conditions"); 
   return check;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkb1"> Check1
 <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return confSubmit('checkb1')" />
</form>

<form action="#">
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkb2"> Check2
 <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return confSubmit('checkb2')" />
</form>
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so very much! I knew there had to be a cleaner way to accomplish this. Thank you thank you!